# setting radius by nrow in AddCircleMarkers, ShinyR, leaflet map

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have 400,000 lines of data for several cities (`data`). I want to visualize their location and also different properties by leaflet. For example I want to set the circle size dependent on the sample number from the given city. I get the correct location but I cannot get the radius changing. I tried this below, where `CityCoordinateData` is a df of 3 columns: single line for all cities, i.e. Location, their Lon and Lat and `unique(data$City)` has the same elements as `CityCoordinateData$Location`

```
m<-leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>% 
      setView(20, 47, zoom = 13) %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(CityCoordinateData$Lon, CityCoordinateData$Lat, radius=nrow(data[grep(CityCoordinateData$Location, data$City),])
```

Grep seems to use only the first element's nrow. I also tried this, it starts to run but never finishes:

```
radius=nrow(subdata[grep(paste(CityCoordinateData$Location,collapse = "|"), data$City, value=TRUE),])
```

Thankful for any tips!

A sample of the data can be simulated like this:

```
CityCoordinateData <- data.frame(Location=as.factor(c("Dorog", "Eger", "Erd")), Lon=c(17,18,19), Lat=c(40,41,42))
data <- data_sample<-data.frame(City=as.factor(c("Dorog", "Eger", "Erd", "Dorog", "Dorog", "Eger")), Variable=c(11,12,13,14,15,16))
```

So I in this example I would like the location "Dorog" marked by a circle with radius 3, "Eger" 2 and "Erd" 1.

Comment: Difficult to answer without any example data but one issue looks to be that your subset command returns the match, for subsetting you need a logical (i.e. use `grepl`) or the integer position of the match (`value = FALSE`)

Comment: Agree with @blmoore, a sample of your data would help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for reactions!! I tried grepl, but still only the first element is used for the radius. I tried to give an example in the original post, see above. In this one all circles would have the radius 3 right now, which is not what i want.

Comment: What we mean is to somehow provide a sample of the original dataset so that the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: You should map radius size (or any other variable, really) to a variable via `~`. For instance, see examples [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your data has several values per location. In case that is correct, there will be several circles per location. This is the code I tried.

```
library(leaflet)

CityCoordinateData <- data.frame(Location=c("Dorog", "Eger", "Erd"), 
                                 Lon=c(17,18,19), Lat=c(40,41,42))
data<-data_sample <- data.frame(City=c("Dorog", "Eger", "Erd", "Dorog", "Dorog", "Eger"), 
                                Variable=c(11,12,13,14,15,16))

names(CityCoordinateData)[1] <- c("City")

xy <- merge(CityCoordinateData, data)

leaflet(data = xy) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~Lon, ~Lat, radius = ~Variable)
```

[image]